# Getting errors while reindexing MarkLogic database

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic 8.

Created a DB and attached 3 forests. DB has 1 million documents.

While reindexing the database I am getting below error.

```
There is currently an exception: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in rebalance of forest rsuite-f2: XDMP-REBALANCE: Error rebalancing fn:doc("/$CONTENT$/65650455/354/20171026133334_50.xml"): SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 16777216 bytes: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
There is currently an exception: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in rebalance of forest rsuite: XDMP-REBALANCE: Error rebalancing fn:doc("/$SEARCH$/34900/34838.xml"): SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 16777216 bytes: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
Information on this page may be missing.
```

Please help me to understand

1. Reason behind this error.
2. What would be the consequences.
3. What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential part of the message is `SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 16777216 bytes: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.`. It looks like your system is low on memory, both physical and swap. Increase either, and restart the forests to allow MarkLogic to recover. I would expect no data to be lost.

HTH!

Comment: System (in C drive) has 15 GB free space. Swap memory, I have increased it to 12288 MB (12 GB).
I restarted the forest but after some time same error is thrown.

Comment: @DixitSingla Swap should be to 2x the amount of ram as mentioned here. https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/21/19/swap-space-requirements

Comment: Forests `data directory` is set to D drive (not the default one). Do I need to increase the swap space for D drive also to 2x of RAM?